# How to assign multiple users to a Jira Task

Tags: jira

I'm wondering how to assign two users to one task in JIRA. I took over a project that was set up by someone else. The problem is we are doing pair programming and we would like to keep track of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think you can not actually assign two users to field `assignee` as it is built-in field.

You can create new required field e.g. `pair-assignee` and have pair tracked there. Here is [a doc about how to setup a custom field](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Adding+a+Custom+Field).

Answer (score 0):

By design, this is not possible as such - it's a single value field.
But there are ways around this limitation.

Since a number of people had this question, Atlassian has set up a [page for the possible solutions/workarounds](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/How+do+I+assign+issues+to+multiple+users).